# view not found? in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i've  a Welcome.aspx in my Customer( Views )folder. but when i redirect the view from my c# coding it finds the below error message.

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Customer/Welcome

what would be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide code how you call the view? If you are using

```
return View();
```

then you should provide just a name of view:

```
return View("Welcome");
```

Comment: my code is return View("Welcome");   but still i have the error

Comment: Could you provide code of your controller and also location of view File? Is it /Views/Customer/Welcome.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

adding to what @dampe said... if you are just doing a "Get" request, you will also need an 
Index() ActionResult in your controller for your "Welcome" View. Your code would be similar to:

`public ActionResult Index()

{

      return View();

}`